# Postgres Recovery Failure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What I am trying to accomplish is a recovery using a continuous archive backup.
I am running a vm of CentOS 6.8 and Postgres 9.1  Postgres 9.1 is the same as the DB that I am pulling from.

I installed Postgres and initialized the DB, started up fine.
Then, following these directions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/continuous-archiving.html

- Stopped the destination pSQL server (as root: service postgresql-9.1 stop)
- Copied the destination cluster data folder to the side (as postgres)
- Removed the cluster data files (as postgres)
- Copied in my source data folder (as postgres)
- Copied WAL files into a clean pg_xlog folder under the data folder (as postgres)
- Created a recovery.conf file which contained:

  > restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/database_sample_backup/wal_archives/0A/%f %p'

This being another location for the WAL files other than the copy I placed in pg_xlog (was not sure if I needed both)

But when I attempt to restart my server, it fails. (as root: service postgresql-9.1 start)
My pgstartup.log at one point spit out "runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted" but it doesn't consistently do this with every attempt to start.

I've also tried turning off archiving and replication directive in postgres.conf (so that it can run stand alone) and tried copying over the pg_hba.conf from the new DB I had created to see if they would resolve the issue.  Neither did.

I've also done a netstat -ntap | grep 5432 which confirmed that I don't have anything else running on the port.

What else can I provide in the form of details, and what else my I attempt in this restoration process.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Can the postgres user set groups etc?

Comment: postgres is the user owner and the group for the new data directory I brought in.  The original has permissions set to 700.  I've also tried 744 and 774 variations but didn't have a change in startup or pgstartup.log output (though when deleted, a new pgstartup.log file was created)

Comment: pgstartup.log is the only log file that I'm aware of.  Is there another one to look for, or another way I can execute my startup that would force a more verbose output?